# IndexOutOfBoundException in ExpandableListView depending on phone maker

Tags: android, expandablelistview

My ExpandableListView working fine on Samsung Device But When I am testing It on Micromax, Sony, Moto G; I am getting error on clicking 2nd Group Item "`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2` " But there is no such error on Samsung Device

Please Help me out.

Comment: Arrays are **0-based**. If **the length is 2**, you can't index **the item number 2** - since it **doesn't exist**! The index range is **0, 1**.

Comment: I know that :) But I am not getting this error on Samsung Phone but on Micromax  ...